# Working of nodejs with asterisk

Tags: node.js, asterisk

I am trying to use `asterisk-manager` with nodejs. I have a running nodejs server at port 3000. Now I want to connect to my asterisk server and for that I am using `asterisk-manager`.

In the node_modules folder I have the package `asterisk-manager`, and in the main `package.json` under dependencies I added the line `"asterisk-manager": "0.1.x"` and restarted the nodejs server.
But when I try to connect to the AMI using:

```
var AsteriskManager = require('asterisk-manager');
var ami = new AsteriskManager('5038','serverip','user','passwd', true);
```

it throws an error: `ReferenceError: AsteriskManager is not defined`

Am I missing anything? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks right, so my guess is that something went wrong installing the npm package for askerisk-manager. Try uninstalling and reinstalling...

```
npm uninstall asterisk-manager --save
npm install asterisk-manager@0.1.x --save
```